# Google Maps Android API fails to load map

Tags: android, google-maps

I know there are many questions like this, but I've verified that everything is set up correctly. The worst part is that it worked perfectly fine until I reinstalled Windows. (I did update it with the newly generated debug key).

**Debug keystore**

[image]

**Google API console**

[image]

[image]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="nl.whileio.ovaub" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <!-- Android 4.0+, almost entire target market nowadays and native action bar is convenient -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!-- Internet and GPS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Google Maps requires these -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!-- OpenGL ES 2.0 required to render maps -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:logo="@drawable/ic_logo" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!-- Google Play services -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Google Maps API key -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyD1xkO8zpfyWP52qqt6cuxnWPU5eOfxZVM" />

        <!-- Main side bar + fragments activity -->
        <activity android:name="nl.whileio.ovaub.view.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Logcat**

This appears right away:

[image]

And this appears about 20 seconds after the app has started:

[image]

That almost makes it look like there are actual network problems. The Google Maps application and other apps load maps fine, however.

**What I have tried:**

- Regenerate API key in API console a few times
- Uninstall and reinstall app after every single change
- Ran `Project -> Clean -> Clean all projects` a couple of dozen times
- Tried the maps API sample with appropriate key and package, made no difference
- Tried signing with a real keystore, also made no difference
- Verified with keytool that the installed APK (cert.rsa) *really* does use the correct debug keystore, which it does
- Restarted my phone

Any ideas what I can do at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a completely new project in the Google API console, which seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

i suggest you came to visit [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-android) to download a sample code of hello map Android from Google it self, then you can follow the tutorial in there, i have a same problem with you, but when i find this the link i gave you, now it's working.. i hope it can help you
Please Read Carefully the tutorial, i'm sure it's working :D

Comment: I already solved the problem, it had nothing to do with the Android project, so that tutorial would not have helped.